# Wi-Fi problem probably with 2.4 GHz networks

Tags: drivers, wireless, dell, iwlwifi, adapter

I've been having problems with Wi-Fi connection on my Dell Latitude E7450. Mostly, I've been using wired connections to get around the problem but now it's starting to annoy me enough to try to solve it, or at least understand what the issue is.

When I'm wireless, my connection often becomes slow or I don't even get any response from the website while browsing, other services such as FTP also don't work properly, but apparently, I'm connected to the network. After some time, I realized that when I switch to 5 GHz, this problem doesn't appear, but I don't know whether I've been on a 2.4 GHz network where I didn't have any issues either. I also have a USB adapter with which I don't have any of these issues at all, so I'm left with either a malfunctioning Wi-Fi adapter or some driver bug.

This is the part where I can't go further. My adapter is Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265. I read it here: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi, that a similar issue can be caused by interference with Bluetooth, but switching it off doesn't help. Can you help me how to get to the root of this problem?

Comment: Situational Wi-Fi problems are usually just that- situational. There are dozens of factors that can affect connection speed. If you're only having problems in specific situations, or on specific networks, then it's probably nothing to do with your hardware or the software/drivers.

Comment: Try first checking if your router is transmitting on the same channel as other routers. It happens when there's too much radio congestion on the same channel. Try to check with WiFi Analyzer (https://www.wifianalyzer.info) which channel is free (or least congested) and switch router to transmit on 2.4GHz with the best channel. Save settings and reboot router.

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?  Also, please provide more details of the issue(s) in how you are seeing them.  Are you having issues with only your own router / access point or are you having issues with everything that you connect to?  If you are having issues connecting to other routers, etc. how do you know if you are connecting to a 2.4Ghz or a 5Ghz connection?  Your WiFi adapter doesn't let you control which frequency you connect to if the SSIDs of the router have both the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz combined with the same name that can cause connection issues.